# CSS Bg color for Table Th

Tags: css

I want to fill the full left column of a table which are TH cells.

when I am trying to use:

```
<th bgcolor="#F2F2F2">some text</th>
```

I have also tried background-color="
The full cell is not filled up with the background color applying to the class used in the TH cell

```
background-color:#F2F2F2;
```

but the result is still the same.
I want to apply the background as a column. (Picture attached)

[image]

How I can achieve it.

update:

```
<th class="col label" scope="row" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">Product Type</th>

#product-attribute-specs-table.table tbody tr th {
    padding: 5px !important;
    border: 0px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

#product-attribute-specs-table .label {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

.label, label {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 9px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

Further Update:

Even when I am applying

```
td{
  background-color:  red;
}
```

The result is like the attached image:

[image]

Comment: share your code

Comment: Html css rendered in firebug or code used which will be more helpful?

Comment: yes the final html rendred

Comment: I have updated it. if you want more info, I will add that.

Comment: it's better to include the full table as shown in the screenshot

Comment: It is required for left column only marked in red.

Answer (score 0):

The question title doesn't match your desired behaviour.. at all.

What you want according to your image is a red border around your first column.

That can be achieved by applying left and right borders to your first tds, top left and right borders to your first th, and bottom left and right borders to your last th first td.

And border-collapse:collapse to the table so no blank spaces between the borders.

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

th:first-of-type{
  border-left:2px solid red;
  border-right:2px solid red;
  border-top:2px solid red;
}

td:first-of-type{
  border-left:2px solid red;
  border-right:2px solid red;
}

tr:last-of-type td:first-of-type{
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Something</th><th>something</th><th>DarkSide</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: ok, so if you want the background-color for the first column, target it with td:first-of-type and th:first-of-type

```css
table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td:first-of-type, th:first-of-type{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Something</th><th>something</th><th>DarkSide</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No I don't want red border around my first column. that is for highlighting the 1st column. I want the Background color for 1st column. what I am saying is the background is not being filled properly. the background is applied to text in the `th`.

Comment: @Joshi ok, I've added that to the answer as well

Comment: Thanks. is it not possible to have a full background without white space between cells.

Comment: I don't know what is creating the issue. If I am applying the same code to the second column it is  working fine, but even with your code, the result is like in the image I have attached (for the 1st column)

Comment: @Joshi white spaces are due to borders. You need to set the border-collapse to prevent them. Check again, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `border-collapse: collapse;` to the whole table to get rid of spaces between cells:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td:first-of-type, th:first-of-type{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Something</th><th>something</th><th>DarkSide</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Something</td><td>something</td><td>DarkSide</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you who tried to help.
but the problem was somewhere else.

I had to remove the label from the class definition of `th` element and background worked perfectly.

Example:

original code:

```
<th class="col label" scope="row" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">Product Type</th>
```

modified code:

```
<th class="col" scope="row" bgcolor="#F2F2F2">Product Type</th>
```